# hdpi ldpi mdpi icon/menu resolution

Tags: android, android-resolution

I want to set an icon for my application, and don't know the exact resolution to put in the three folders hdpi/ldpi/mdpi . Also i want to set icons to my menu options and don't know what resolution to apply.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Everything you need to know is [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20110501154433/http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html) in the official documentation.

Comment: That's exactly what i'm looking for! i searched in the doc and i didn't find this awesome link. Thanks :).

Comment: This link expired, rotted, and was repurposed by its URI's owner; it's now a promotional redirect for [a graphic design implementation guide](https://material.io/design/iconography/) for [Google Material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_Design)-themed icons. **[Please don't do this.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/202692)**

Answer (score 16):

Launcher icons

```
48 × 48 (mdpi)
72 × 72 (hdpi)
96 × 96 (xhdpi)
144 × 144 (xxhdpi)
192 × 192 (xxxhdpi)
512 × 512 (Google Play store).png
```

Action bar, Dialog & Tab icons

```
24 × 24 area in 32 × 32 (mdpi)
36 × 36 area in 48 × 48 (hdpi)
48 × 48 area in 64 × 64 (xhdpi)
72 × 72 area in 96 × 96 (xxhdpi)
96 × 96 area in 128 × 128 (xxxhdpi)
```

.png These icons are used in the action bar menu. The first number is the size of the icon area, and the second is file size.

Notification icons

```
 22 × 22 area in 24 × 24 (mdpi) 
 33 × 33 area in 36 × 36 (hdpi)
 44 × 44 area in 48 × 48 (xhdpi)
 66 × 66 area in 72 × 72 (xxhdpi)
 88 × 88 area in 96 × 96 (xxxhdpi)
```

.png These are used to represent application notifications in the status bar. They should be flat (no gradients), white and face-on perspective

Small Contextual Icons

```
16 × 16 (mdpi)
24 × 24 (hdpi)
32 × 32 (xhdpi)
48 × 48 (xxhdpi)
64 × 64 (xxxhdpi)
```

.png 
Small icons are used to surface actions and/or provide status for specific items. For example, in the Gmail app, each message has a star icon that marks the message as important.

For more information, use the android developers iconography material.

http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Answer (score 5):

This Link is Help you To set Images for Your Application

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html

Other than Below Link is also may help You....

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html

Answer (score 4):

for app's icon:

ldpi should be 36 x 36

mdpi should be 48 x 48

hdpi should be 72 x 72

xhdpi should be 96 x 96

xxhdpi should be 144 x 144